# Strange case of HTTP headers: If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match

Tags: apache, http, curl, http-headers

As part of a test application, I'm making HTTP requests to webpages. On receiving a response, I save the current date/time (GMT) and ETag header for subsequent requests. However, for some strange reason, some host servers are not validating the If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match headers on subsequent requests.

One such example is this webpage: [www.foxsports.com/nba/cleveland-cavaliers-team-news](http://www.foxsports.com/nba/cleveland-cavaliers-team-news#skipconditionalget=1) (running Apache). It always returns the full body with a 200-Ok HTTP status, when a 304-NotModified status is expected, hence ignoring the If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match headers sent in the request. I tested it using curl and online [Hurl](https://www.hurl.it).

Any ideas why the sent request headers are not validated by some host servers?

Comment: Looks like your server isn't configured correctly. Here is how you can do that http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/caching.html

Comment: The other way, you can do it in you code manually, by checking ETag, end sending back correct response.

Comment: @Vitaly, the webpages are external, so the servers are not under my control. Is there a way to workaround this issue from the client-end, maybe by relying on the 'Expires' header instead?

Comment: If it's not your site, and it uses ETag for caching, then probably you have no workaround there. You have to control backend to adjust caching mechanism.